# How to indentify matching type in generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class of

```
public class Mapper<K, L, V> : Dictionary<K, V>
```

When I instantiate it as

```
Mapper<string, string, MapSource> Map= new Mapper<string, string, MapSource>();
```

and try and do

```
Map["..."].
```

is comes back with compiler error message of

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'MinorTesting.XML.Sourcer.Mapper.this[L]' and 'MinorTesting.XML.Sourcer.Mapper.this[K]'

How would I fix this to remove the compile .

Bob.

Comment: FYI it is a bad programming practice to declare a generic type such that under reasonable constructions, there are signatures which unify. There are situations in which doing so causes implementation-defined behaviour in the CLR. Avoid, avoid, avoid. Either never construct your type such that a signature unifies, or, if it is by design to have a <string, string, whatever> map then design the public surface of the class such that methods which would unify have different names.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I eventually abandoned it. An easier solution presented itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does `MultiKeyDictionary` look like and where/how is it used?

It looks like `MultiKeyDictionary` provides two indexers, `this[L]` and `this[K]`. When `L` and `K` are the same then the compiler is unable to choose between those indexers because they've effectively both become `this[string]`.

One option would be to provide explicit methods to use in place of the indexer in this case: for example, `GetByKey(K)` and `GetByValue(L)` or similar.

Comment: It is a multidictionary, which I wasn't really aware of. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 5):

So your class looks like this:

```
public class MultiKeyDictionary<K, L, V>
{
    public V this[K key]
    {
        get { return... }
    }

    public V this[L key]
    {
        get { return... }
    }
}
```

So if both `K` and `L` are `string` in your constructed type, you essentially have this:

```
public class MultiKeyDictionary
{
    public V this[string key]
    {
        get { return... }
    }

    public V this[string key]
    {
        get { return... }
    }
}
```

Obviously this won't work. The problem is with the specific generics approach here - you could safely support two keys of the same type by replacing the Item properties with something like:

```
public V GetByK(K key)
{
    ...
}

public V GetByL(L key)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent work dude. It does implement two indexers as above.

Answer (score 0):

Your class inherits from `Dictionary<K, V>`, which **implicitly** defines the `this[K]` accessor into your class. When you define the `this[L]` accessor explicitly, and `K` and `V` coincide, you get the conflict.

You should not inherit from `Dictionary`, in my opinion. You might want to **encapsulate** a dictionary for internal usage.

Answer (score 0):

May be simply like this.

```
public class Mapper<K, L, V> : Dictionary<K, V>
{
     public V this[K key1, L Key2]
    {
        get { return  (key1 != null) ? dic[key1] : dic[Key2]; }
    }

}
```

To access this

```
Mapper<string, string, int> a = new Mapper<string, string, int>();
var s = a[null, "sam"];
```